# Как отправить сообщения на канал в viber по API?

Tags: api, бот, viber, viber-api

Как можно по API отправлять на канал сообщение?

умею делать вайбер бота, но вроде как его подцепить к каналу нельзя, по аналогии как у телеграма (подцепил бота и бот шлет на канал)

Answer (score 1):

Это может сделать сама поддержка Вайбера. Подключала себе такого в группу, сделали быстро, за сутки.
В группе должно быть более 1000участников.
Нужно создать запрос по этой ссылке: https://help.viber.com/en/contact